# Arrow/icon Toggle right/end of button and text left/start

Tags: css

I have been searching and trying but I can not get this to work. I have a button with a arrow in it that transform on click. My problem is that the arrow is at the start of the button. I need it to be at the end of the button but i need the tekst to be left. All things I tried and could find where making the tekst to display at the end to.

The button:

```
 <button class="btn-toggle hass-menuhead align-items-center collapsed MenuStatus" type="button" data-menuitem="show_com" data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
        data-bs-target="#Communication-collapse" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false">
    Communication 
        </button>
```

The original CSS where the arrow is left:

```
 .btn-toggle {
      display: inline-flex;
      align-items: center;
      padding: .25rem .4rem;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: rgb(199, 200, 201);
      background: rgb(var(--hass-bg-td-color), 0.6); 
    }
    .btn-toggle:hover,
    .btn-toggle:focus {
    
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        
        transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
      
    }
    
    .btn-toggle::before {
      width: 1.25em;
      line-height: 0;
      content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3e%3cpath fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='2' d='M5 14l6-6-6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
      transition: transform .35s ease;
      transform-origin: .5em 50%;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    
    .btn-toggle[aria-expanded="true"] {
      color: rgb(246 242 242); 
        background: rgb(var(--hass-bg-thead-color));
    }
    .btn-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You could use `::after` instead of `::before`, if you want the image after the word, instead of before the word...?

Comment: Yes that works.. How i never thought of that.. Seemingly it was a sump question. Sorry for asking. Thanks for answering !

Comment: Now all that remains. How to have the arrow display at the end of the button. It now is aligning with the text.